# Why is it a wrong practice to calculate voltage drop across current source?

Tags: current-source

I understand that an ideal current source always delivers the same current regardless of voltage applied across it. However, in a circuit with no switches, voltages and currents do not change over time so the current source should maintain a constant voltage across it. Why is it wrong to consider voltage across it when doing KVL in meshes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with calculating the voltage across a current source.

But to do so you'd use KVL and find a sequence of other branches between its terminals, the sum of whose voltages would equal the voltage across the source.

There's no way to calculate the voltage of the current source just from knowing what the current is through it (or through other branches in the circuit like you would do for a CCCS). Therefore it's not useful in forming an equation for mesh analysis.

Comment: > But to do so you'd use KVL and find a sequence of other branches between its terminals, the sum of whose voltages would equal the voltage across the source.   
Sorry im still learning so bear with me. Why cant we just multiply the current coming out of the source with the impedance/resistances then equating sum of voltage drops to the voltage across current source just like we would do for a battery?

Comment: Because, if you look at a current source as a very large voltage source in series with a resistor, the value of the resistor is not (in and of itself) defined, so the drop across it cannot (in isolation) be determined. In fact, for real-world current sources it's important to find the voltage output required for operation. This voltage, called compliance, has a maximum determined by the circuit and the power supplies, and forms a limiting factor in the operation of the source. For instance, driving 1 mA through a 100k resistor requires 100 volts, and a circuit powered by 15 volts won't work.

Comment: @az_1993, you can do that to find the voltage across the current source, like I said in my second paragraph. But it won't give you an independent equation to use for mesh analysis. (Because you used all those other branch voltages to get the source voltage, you can't now use the source voltage to find the other branch voltages)